# Toshibha tecra Z40 two-finger-scroll

Tags: 12.04, scrolling

Recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.05 on my new Toshiba Tecra Z40A, how to enable two-finger-scroll. Can you please help me.

Comment: Try Ubuntu 14.04.3 from LiveUSB.

Answer (score 2):

Type in terminal:

```
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```

If it works, then create a new Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Save it to file using gedit (or any other text editor) and add that script to *Startup Applications*, so it will enable two finger scrolling every time you start your computer.

Alternatively you can upgrade your system to 14.04 or newer and you will be able to just enable this option in *System Settings* → *Mouse & Touchpad*.